# How do I insert a row into a table in Word using VBA Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am trying to insert a row into a table in a Word document using Access 2007 VBA.  I have tried ListRows, Rows, Insert, EntireRow.Insert, etc.  I have found Microsoft's help for 2010+ but nothing that works for 2007.  I'm pretty sure its because I don't understand the syntax on how to execute the insert properly.  Below is my code, can anyone help?  My Word document has 1 table which has 1 row with 7 columns.  Thanx!

```
Public Sub documentBilletingReserve()
    ' Create pointers to Word Document
    Dim objWord As Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document 'doc As Word.Document
    Dim bolOpenedWord As Boolean

    ' Get pointer to Word Document
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        ' If Word is not opened, open it
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        bolOpenedWord = True
    End If

    objWord.Visible = True ' Set this to true if you want to see the document open 
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Create New Blank Document
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add("Z:\08_Volume Management\ACCESS\EMAILTEMPLATES\BilletingRequest.dotx") 

    'Create Excel Table in Word doc to populate request
    Dim currentRow As Integer
    currentRow = 2
    Dim objRange
    Dim objTable

    Set objRange = objDoc.Range
    'objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, intNoOfRows, intNoOfColumns
    Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
    'objTable.Borders.Enable = False ' Set to true to see the borders
    'objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "RM"

    ' Loop through delegates

    ' Pick Names Delegate Names
    Dim finishedSearch As Boolean
    Dim counterDelegate As Integer
    counterDelegate = 2
    finishedSearch = False

    MMRank = DLookup("[Rank]", "ModelManagers", "[ID] = " + CStr(counterDelegate))
    MMFirstName = DLookup("[FirstName]", "ModelManagers", "[ID] = " + CStr(counterDelegate))
    MMLastName = DLookup("[LastName]", "ModelManagers", "[ID] = " + CStr(counterDelegate))

    objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.InsertAfter Text:="RM"

    ‘************************************************************
    ‘********** INSERT ROW TO TABLE IN WORD HERE
    ‘************************************************************
    Set rowNew = objTable.ListObject.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)
    rowNew.Range.cells(1, 1).Value = MMGender

    objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = CStr(currentRow - 1)
    objTable.Cell(2, 3).Range.Text = MMRank
    objTable.Cell(2, 4).Range.Text = MMFirstName + " " + MMLastName
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
    ‘************************************************************

    ' This will shift the focus to Word
    'objWord.Activate

    'Save New Document
    'On Error Resume Next

    Dim stringFilename As String
    stringFilename = "Z:\08_Volume Management\ACCESS\EMAILATTACHMENTS\BilletingRequest" + [VolumeName] + ".docx"

    'On Error Resume Next
    objDoc.SaveAs (stringFilename)
    'On Error Resume Next

    'On Error GoTo 0

    'Close and release pointers
    objDoc.Close False 'doc.Close False
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    If bolOpenedWord = True Then
        'Close Word
        objWord.Quit
    End If

    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: How does Word do it? What I mean is turn on record macro, do what you want through the UI and look at the code Word generates.

Answer (score 0):

The `Selection` object has `InsertRowsAbove` and `InsertRowsBelow` methods. One row is added if you don't specify a different parameter.

```
objTable.Select
Selection.InsertRowsBelow 5
```

or

```
objTable.Rows(objTable.Rows.Count).InsertRowsBelow
```