# Exporting Access query data into MS Word table

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am trying to move the data from a query to a table in MS Word.

[image: Closing Tracking Form]

When we close a case, we need to create a document that includes demographic data and a list of important dates.
The table needs borders (underline on the date), and to be inserted midway through the document. (I think bookmarks are the way to go).

I tried Power Query (which does not allow the user to set parameters or prompt for criteria).

My initial thoughts are to create a recordset from the query and then create a loop to insert the data into the table.

All the posts I found deal with creating the table in Word as the sole object.
I also can't find how to point the recordset to a bookmark or particular table.

The user will generate the document from Access. (Right now, it will put certain dates, like open and close, into the corresponding Form Field in a Word template.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470726/how-do-i-insert-a-row-into-a-table-in-word-using-vba-access-2007 shows adding a table row and data from access

Comment: That looks great, but it seems that it is merely creating the table as the whole document and not at a certain point.  Is there a way to direct the table to be created at a bookmark?

Comment: I am sure there is. You should do research and when you have code with specific issue, post question. Start with https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/444299-access-table-outputto-word-bookmark

Comment: Yes you can add the table to replace the bookmark.  Try it out and post back with code if you run into problems.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing the right direction-at least knowing it exists as a possibility is helpful.  I am certain my first attempt will be terrible, but we'll go from there.

Comment: You could even use a mailmerge to output just the record you're interested in. Such a mailmerge could even be automated from Access.

Answer (score 0):

With gratitude, I want to post the code for the solution. Of course, there is probably a better way to do it, but the solution works, and best of all I know why it works.

```
    Public Function concatData() As String
    Dim retVal As String
    Dim rsHeader As Long, rsCounter As Long
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Val As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    
     'This code puts the query into a recordset, which is then formatted into a table later

    Val = [Forms]![FrmAllTracker]![CaseID]
    strSQL = "Select * From QryTrackerInitRecRecv WHERE [CaseID] = " & Val
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    'Get headers
    'For rsHeader = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    '    retVal = retVal & rs.Fields(rsHeader).Name & vbTab
    'Next
    'Replace last TAb with a carriage return
    'retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - 1) & vbCr

    Do While Not rs.EOF
       'Get all records
        For rsCounter = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            retVal = retVal & rs.Fields(rsCounter).Value & vbTab
        Next
        retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - 1) & vbCr
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    concatData = retVal
    End Function

    Private Sub BtnGenTracker_Click()
    If IsNull(Me.CaseClosed) Then
    
    MsgBox "Please Enter a Close Date", _
        vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    
    Exit Sub
    End If
        ' Create pointers to Word Document
        Dim wd As Word.Application
        Dim doc As Word.Document 'doc As Word.Document
        Dim bolOpenedWord As Boolean
        
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim Tbl As Word.Table
        Dim MDate As String
        MDate = Format([CaseOpen], "mm-dd-yyyy")
       
        ' Get pointer to Word Document
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
        If Err.Number = 429 Then
            ' If Word is not opened, open it
            Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            bolOpenedWord = True
        End If
    
        wd.Visible = True ' Set this to true if you want to see the document open
        On Error GoTo 0
      
       Set doc = wd.Documents.Add("\\gsmstore2\COE\Testing Database\TFT1.docx")
       
     DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="FrmRelRecSenAll"
    With doc
    On Error Resume Next
    
    'sends particular fields to corresponding FormFields in Word
    .FormFields("PtName").Result = [Forms]![FrmAllTracker]![FrmSubTherapyRef].[Form].[Text62]
    .FormFields("COENum").Result = Me.COEMR
    .FormFields("RefRec").Result = Me.CaseOpen
    .FormFields("FirstCont").Result = Me.CaseOpen
    .FormFields("InitRecsRecv").Result = DLookup("FirstOfRecordsRec", "QryTrackerInitRecRecvCFFirst")
    .FormFields("SuffRecs").Result = Me.SuffRecDate
    .FormFields("Init2").Result = Me.InitCaseDate
    
    .FormFields("TeamRev").Result = DLookup("ContactDate", "QryTrackerTeamRev", "[ContactType] = 14")
    .FormFields("MCRMeet").Result = DLookup("ContactDate", "QryTrackerTeamRev", "[ContactType] = 6")
    .FormFields("MCRMeetAct").Result = DLookup("ContactDate", "QryTrackerTeamRev", "[ContactType] = 6")
    .FormFields("FTDate").Result = InputBox("Please enter Date of FT Release", "FT Release", Default)
    .FormFields("FirstAppt").Result = InputBox("Please enter Date of 1st offered appt", "1st Offered Date", Default)
    .FormFields("AssessDebrief").Result = DLookup("ContactDate", "QryTrackerTeamRev", "[ContactType] = 15")
    .FormFields("RptSent").Result = DLookup("ContactDate", "QryTrackerTeamRev", "[ContactType] = 11")
    .FormFields("FFollow").Result = DLookup("ContactDate", "QryTrackerTeamRev", "[ContactType] = 12")
    .FormFields("LFollow").Result = DLookup("ContactDate", "QryTrackerLFollow")
    .FormFields("CaseClosed").Result = Me.CaseClosed
    
    If Not IsNull(DLookup("ContactDate", "QryTrackerTeamRev", "[ContactType] = 4")) Then
    .FormFields("Bill").Result = "Yes"
    Else
    .FormFields("Bill").Result = "No"
    End If
    
    .Application.Activate
        Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Releases").Range
        
        rng.Text = concatData()
        Set Tbl = rng.ConvertToTable
       End With
            
        'This foramats the table
        With Tbl
            .Columns(1).Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .Columns(1).Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
            .Columns(1).Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
            .Columns(1).Borders.InsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
            .Columns(1).Width = 125
            .Columns(2).Width = 450
            .Columns(3).Delete
           
        End With
        
    wd.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 ("\\Filelocation\COE\Case Files\" & COEMR & "\Tracking Sheet" & " " & MDate & ".docx")
    Set doc = Nothing
    Set wd = Nothing
    Set rg = Nothing
    Set Tbl = Nothing
    
    End Sub
```